# ajax with function value in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to work with ajax with function value.
I have a label for instance with "id=36" which i get by OnClick in html:

```
id="<?=$row['customer_id'];?>" onclick="test(this.id)">
```

Now  i need to work trough it.
my java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(clicked_id) {    
        var value = { 'id' : 36; };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url('test/ret(id)'); ?>',
            data: value,
            success: function(resp) {
                $('#data').html(resp);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I know something is wrong!!! But what?!
The id i get i correct but how can i send and use it in java script?
The var value doesn't get 'id' and i think

```
 url: '<?php echo site_url('test/ret(id)'); ?>'
```

Is so incorrect! How can i send id trough function?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38703824/edit) the question and show your controller code.

Comment: You don't need `id` in URL. It is already passed through POST variable. Just grab it with `$this->input->post('id')` in your for example `Test.php` controller in `ret()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(clicked_id) {    

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('test'); ?>',
        data: { id: clicked_id },
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#data').html(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

and get on that page using

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses... Specially @Tpojka :)
The problem were semicolon after "var id = 36" and as Tpojka said, id will pass through POST and doesn't need to write "test/ret(id)".
The working code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(clicked_id) {    
        var value = { 'id' : clicked_id };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url('test/ret'); ?>',
            data: value,
            success: function(resp){
                $('#error').html(resp);
            }
        });    
    }
</script>
```

And in test controller in ret method, I just grab id with

```
$this->input->post('id')
```